# JDK 11.0.2 compilation fails with javac NPE on anonymous parameterized class type inference

Tags: java, javac, type-inference, java-11, compiler-bug

**Code** (spring-web 5.1.2)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "token");
    HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    ResponseEntity<Object> test = restTemplate.exchange(
            "https://example.com",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity<>(headers),
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() { // fails here
            });
}
```

**OracleJDK 1.8** (expected output)

> cannot infer type arguments for
>   org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference
>
> reason: cannot use '<>' with anonymous inner classes

**OracleJDK 11.0.2** (not expected output)

> compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug
>   arguments=11.0.2, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:1235)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1634)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:398)
>     at
>   jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$FlowAnalyzer.visitVarDef(Flow.java:989) 
>   ...

If I change diamond operator to explicit type

`new ParameterizedTypeReference<>(){}` to `new ParameterizedTypeReference<Object>(){}`

then the code compiles successfully on both JDKs.

Is it a known compiler bug?

Comment: An exception from the compiler is a bug. Write up a test case and submit the bug.

Comment: I confirm this bug as well

Comment: I am not able to build the project while my other team mates are able to build it . I tried to delete my repo . no luck .

Comment: This is a bug in any version older than 11.0.8. Try upgrading your JDK to 11.0.8 or newer

Comment: JDK 11.0.14 works, haven't tried earlier versions.

Comment: JDK 11.0.15 also worked for me

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Bug ([JDK-8212586](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212586)) has been already submitted and [fixed](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/bbbc110cdffe) in version 12.

Minimal, verifiable example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Bug<>(){};
}

static class Bug<T> {

    Bug() {
        test(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>(){});
    }

    void test(ParameterizedTypeReference<T> typeReference) {
    }
}
```

[Some Details.](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2018-November/012592.html)

---

Fix has been also backported to JDK 11 - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8220578.

Available starting JDK **11.0.4**.

Comment: Does "fixed in version 12" mean that I need to install JDK 12 to get the fix?  Will JDK 11 remain broken?

Comment: @TroyDaniels yes fix is included and scheduled to be released as part of JDK 12. https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/12/

Comment: what about JDK11 which "supposed" to be LTE?

Comment: @MirceaStanciu [fix has been backported](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8220578) and will be available in JDK 11.0.4. Updated the answer.

Comment: java 11.0.6 has the same problem

Comment: Some consusion about versions: in openjdk it is fixed 11.0.4 onwards, oracle jdk 11.0.8. See original bug report [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210197).

Comment: thanks this post saved me,was unable to figure out wats wrong,literally no stack trace pointing to this change

Answer (score 10):

As pointed out in previous comments, the problem is with parametrized anonymous classes, e.g. when using TypeToken from Guava, this does **NOT** work:

```
public List<SomeClass> list() {
    return getData(new TypeToken<>() { });
}
```

But this **DOES** work:

```
public List<SomeClass> list() {
    return getData(new TypeToken<List<SomeClass>>() { });
}
```

I tried that in versions 11.0.3 - 11.0.7 versions and all contains the bug.

Comment: OpenJDK 11.0.8 has the bug too

Comment: I did with 11.0.12 and it works.

Answer (score 9):

I Had the same error,you need to create a function :

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<Object> createParameterizedTypeReference(){ return new ParameterizedTypeReference<>(){}; }
```

and call it :

```
ResponseEntity<Object> test = restTemplate.exchange(
"https://example.com",
HttpMethod.GET,
new HttpEntity<>(headers),
createParameterizedTypeReference() { 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Java 11.0.7 has the same problem.

This changed from:

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
})
```

to this:

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<HashMap<String, MyClass>>() {
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this problem on my machine by upgrading to AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.8.

https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html#x64_mac-jdk

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, this error doesn't tell you the originating class so it's very hard to intentionally reproduce the problem. After trying a lot, I finally updated project JDK to 11.0.16 (from 11.0.7) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else faces this issue: we had to change the java compiler from javac to eclipse (anything else that's not javac) to get our code to compile. Upgrading/downgrading jdk didn't fix the issue for us.

[image: settings on intellij idea]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I **intalled latest java 11 from oracle** (Java SE Development Kit 11.0.19) and it solved problem. You can download latest version here : https://www.oracle.com/pl/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html