# Why am I getting a runtime compile error from Maven?

Tags: maven

I have a library (with annotations and an annotation processor) and a web project.

I am using Netbeans on MacOS and Tomcat.

The web project compiles correctly, the annotation/processor is working correctly.

But when I go to run I get a compiler error involving Maven and Codehaus:

```
compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.10, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findType(Resolve.java:2280)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInternal(Resolve.java:2355)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdent(Resolve.java:2341)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveIdent(Resolve.java:2602)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitIdent(Attr.java:3488)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent.accept(JCTree.java:2248)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:655)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:715)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:708)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.attributeAnnotationValues(Annotate.java:458)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.attributeAnnotation(Annotate.java:415)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.annotateNow(Annotate.java:341)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.lambda$annotateLater$0(Annotate.java:267)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:191)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.unblockAnnotations(Annotate.java:144)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:157)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterDone(JavaCompiler.java:1741)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.enterTrees(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1202)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1088)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1108)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1345)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:936)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDK 11.0.2 compilation fails with javac NPE on anonymous parameterized class type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775253/jdk-11-0-2-compilation-fails-with-javac-npe-on-anonymous-parameterized-class-typ)

Answer (score 1):

In pom.xml, removing this particular line under the plugin section of org.apache.maven.plugins works for me.

```
<version>3.5.1</version>
```